# Pytest collecting same test multiple times

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test file with 3 tests. The tests need a parameter passed via command line. On running `pytest --serial-port [port name]` it says "**collected 15 items**". Though it should only be 3!

**test_xyz.py**

```
import os
import time
import serial
from plot import plot_file


def test_abc(serial_port):
    # test code here


def test_xyz(serial_port):
    # test code here


def test_pqr(serial_port):
    # test code here
```

**conftest.py**

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--serial-port", help="Target serial port")
    parser.addoption('--count', default=1, type='int', metavar='count',
                     help='Run each test the specified number of times')


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "serial_port" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        serial_port = metafunc.config.getoption("serial_port")
        if serial_port:
            metafunc.parametrize("serial_port", serial_port)
        else:
            raise EnvironmentError('Target serial port not specified. Use --serial-port [serial port]')
```

**Environment:**
Python 3.8.1
Pytest 5.3.5

Comment: it depends on how many times you are calling those functions !

Comment: They are not called from anywhere. I rely on pytest to discover and call them

Comment: what's in your `conftest.py`?

Comment: @Hoenie updated question with `conftest.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running pytest with a serial-port consisting of 5 digits like:

`pytest --serial-port 12345`

And you have 3 functions in your `test_xyz.py`.

So what is happening? You are parametrizing the serial-port, which is a string. The tests are actually running with the values 
`serial_port = "1"` to `serial_port = "5"`.

This line in `conftest.py` results in tests being called 5 * 3 times.

```py
metafunc.parametrize("serial_port", serial_port)
```

You could change your `conftest` to:

```py
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--serial-port", help="Target serial port")
    parser.addoption('--count', default=1, type='int', metavar='count',
                     help='Run each test the specified number of times')

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def serial_port(request):
    port = request.config.option.serial_port
    if port is None:
        pytest.skip()
    return port
```

Comment: That's probably it, per the doc Metafunc.parametrize takes comma-separated argnames and an argvalues which "If only one argname was specified argvalues is a list of values.". Since python strings have the interface of a list of 1-char strings that'll go through just fine producing unexpected output.